# select highest dates even if duplicate

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database that has a column with dates. These dates can vary, some have same dates. How do I select the highest group of dates even if they are duplicate?

This is what I'm using and it's only bringing up the first instance:

```
    SELECT data.Company,data.Eff_Date, data.Monthly_Rate, data.Plan,        
    zips.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE AS Expr1, zips.State, zips.County, zips.City, zips.Zipcode
    FROM data INNER JOIN
    zips ON data.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE = zips.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE
    WHERE (zips.Zipcode = '27012') AND
    (data.Company_Old LIKE '%CSI%') AND
    (data.Plan IN ('A','C','F','F (High)','G','N')) AND
    (data.Gender = 'Female') AND
    (data.Age = '65') AND
    (data.Tobacco = 'Non-Tobacco') AND
    (data.State = 'NC')
    Order by max(data.Eff_Date);
```

Sample for database date:

```
    +------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-----
    | Company_Old | Plan | State | Tobacco | Eff_Date   | Age  | Gender  | ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE |
    +------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-----
    |    CSI      |   A  |   NC  |    No   | 2012-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   C  |   NC  |    No   | 2012-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   F  |   NC  |    No   | 2012-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   FH |   NC  |    No   | 2012-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   G  |   NC  |    No   | 2012-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   N  |   NC  |    No   | 2012-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   A  |   NC  |    No   | 2011-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   C  |   NC  |    No   | 2011-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   F  |   NC  |    No   | 2011-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   FH |   NC  |    No   | 2011-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   G  |   NC  |    No   | 2011-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
    |    CSI      |   N  |   NC  |    No   | 2011-12-01 |  65  |  Male   | 123
```

sample data for database zips:

```
    +-----------------+-------+--------+------+------------+
    | ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE | STATE | COUNTY | CITY |  Zipcode   |           
    +-----------------+-------+--------+------+------------+
    |    123          |   NC  | BLah   | city |  27007     |
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this ::

```
SELECT data.Company,

MAX(data.Eff_Date), data.Monthly_Rate, data.Plan,        
    zips.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE AS Expr1, zips.State, zips.County, zips.City, zips.Zipcode
    FROM data INNER JOIN
    zips ON data.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE = zips.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE
    WHERE (zips.Zipcode = '27012') AND
    (data.Company_Old LIKE '%CSI%') AND
    (data.Plan IN ('A','C','F','F (High)','G','N')) AND
    (data.Gender = 'Female') AND
    (data.Age = '65') AND
    (data.Tobacco = 'Non-Tobacco') AND
    (data.State = 'NC')
    GROUP BYdata.Eff_Date
```

Comment: still only brings up one entry.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using a subquery to retrieve the `max(eff_date)` by each company and then join that subquery to the rest:

```
SELECT d.Company, 
  d.Eff_Date, 
  d.Monthly_Rate, 
  d.Plan,        
  z.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE AS Expr1, 
  z.State, 
  z.County, 
  z.City, 
  z.Zipcode
FROM data d
INNER JOIN zips z
  ON d.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE = z.ZIP_LOOKUP_CODE
INNER JOIN 
(
  select max(Eff_Date) Eff_Date, Company, Plan
  from data
  group by company, Plan
) d1
  on d.Eff_Date = d1.Eff_Date
  and d.company = d1.company
  and d.plan = d1.plan
WHERE (z.Zipcode = '27012') AND
    (d.Company_Old LIKE '%CSI%') AND
    (d.Plan IN ('A','C','F','F (High)','G','N')) AND
    (d.Gender = 'Female') AND
    (d.Age = '65') AND
    (d.Tobacco = 'Non-Tobacco') AND
    (d.State = 'NC')
Order by d.Eff_Date;
```

Comment: Brings up multiple dates, not the highest set of dates (even if duplicate date fields).

Comment: @Eric can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data?

Comment: I added some sample data to the original post. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Eric based on the sample what do you except to return?

Comment: Sorry, there should have been another column for "Rate" as well. It will be returning the rates for Plans A, C, F, FH, G, and N.

Comment: @Eric I made a slight update, you should be able to use a subquery and group by the company and plan, then join that data to the rest.

Comment: Tried, and it returns an empty result :/